# JQuery remove element makes page become not responsive and browser hang

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i try to do loop to remove element in my html using JQuery, but when the function to remove element run, my browser hang and i have to kill the process because the page become unresponsive, here's JQuery  code:

```
function removeElement(){
            var i =0;
            for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
              if ($('#attribute-name'+i).length > 0){
                  $('#attribute-name'+i).remove();
                  $('#attribute-custom'+i).remove(); 
              } else{
                break;
              }
            }
          }
```

my Html :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='attribute-name0'></td>
    <td id='attribute-custom0'></td>
    <td id='attribute-name1'></td>
    <td id='attribute-custom1'></td>
    <td id='attribute-name2'></td>
    <td id='attribute-custom2'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Call `remove` method. `.remove()`. Let me know if that works. You can even do this with single lines `$('[id^="attribute-name"], [id^="attribute-custom"]').remove()`

Comment: @Tushar still same problem

Comment: Try `$('[id^="attribute-name"], [id^="attribute-custom"]').remove()`. Are you sure this code is causing problem?

Comment: How and when/where you call your function, which, btw, works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/t96o98rf/ (with few mentioned fixes).

Comment: @sinisake i call it after getting response from ajax

Comment: @IdhamChoudry, could you provide that code? Probably - somewhere you have infinite loop...

Comment: @sinisake turnout my remove code is fine, there's something wrong with my others code, but the remove code only runs 1 time, when i try to call it again, it doesnt remove anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner instead:

```
$("td:regex(id, attribute-name\d)").remove()
$("td:regex(id, attribute-custom\d)").remove()
```

First, we are selecting all the elements using a regex selector and then we call `remove` methods to delete all nodes.

Comment: why div? the id is inside tr tag

Comment: @IdhamChoudry My bad! I fixed it.